# Configure error with Mac OS X 10.8.5 Xcode 5.0.2: clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value) clang: error: no input files

Tags: xcode, clang, osx-mountain-lion, configure

on MacOSX 10.8.5, after upgrading to Xcode 5.0.2 (and upgrading/installing the Command Line Tools (from within Xcode preferences) I was installing FFTW 3.3.3 and Open MPI 1.6.5 by configuring them from the sources. I get the same type of error in both config.log files in the configure step, which shows the problem is not with the programs as I downloaded them from the official websites.

In short, the first error I see in the both logs is:

```
configure:3750: checking for gcc
configure:3766: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:3777: result: gcc
configure:4006: checking for C compiler version
configure:4015: gcc --version >&5
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
configure:4026: $? = 0
configure:4015: gcc -v >&5
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
configure:4026: $? = 0
configure:4015: gcc -V >&5
clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang: error: no input files
configure:4026: $? = 1
configure:4015: gcc -qversion >&5
clang: error: no input files
```

when I type:

```
alexey-sorokin:local admin$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

when I type some commands to check what is the problem I get similar error to the log:

```
alexey-sorokin:local admin$ gcc -V
clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang: error: no input files
alexey-sorokin:local admin$ clang -v
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
alexey-sorokin:local admin$ which clang
/usr/bin/clang
alexey-sorokin:local admin$ gcc
clang: error: no input files
```

See my config.log file for FFTW3.3.3 installation below. The log for OpenMPI1.6.5 looks very similar, I can upload it in the next message if needed. I could not upload the ful log in the body so I made it shorter.
Any help/insights much appreciated! Thank you all!

++++CONFIG.LOG+++++FFTW3.3.3installation

It was created by fftw configure 3.3.3, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local

```
## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = alexey-sorokin
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 12.5.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.48.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.48.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 8.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 120 tasks, 548 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 1.22, Mach factor: 2.76
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2742: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2810: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2821: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2871: result: yes
configure:3012: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:3051: result: ./install-sh -c -d
configure:3064: checking for gawk
configure:3094: result: no
configure:3064: checking for mawk
configure:3094: result: no
configure:3064: checking for nawk
configure:3094: result: no
configure:3064: checking for awk
configure:3080: found /usr/bin/awk
configure:3091: result: awk
configure:3102: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:3124: result: yes
configure:3208: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:3217: result: no
configure:3265: checking build system type
configure:3279: result: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
configure:3299: checking host system type
configure:3312: result: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
configure:3750: checking for gcc
configure:3766: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:3777: result: gcc
configure:4006: checking for C compiler version
configure:4015: gcc --version >&5
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
configure:4026: $? = 0
configure:4015: gcc -v >&5
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
configure:4026: $? = 0
configure:4015: gcc -V >&5
clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang: error: no input files
configure:4026: $? = 1
configure:4015: gcc -qversion >&5
clang: error: no input files
configure:4026: $? = 1
configure:4046: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:4068: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
configure:4072: $? = 0
configure:4120: result: yes
configure:4123: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:4125: result: a.out
configure:4131: checking for suffix of executables
configure:4138: gcc -o conftest    conftest.c  >&5
configure:4142: $? = 0
configure:4164: result: 
configure:4186: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:4194: gcc -o conftest    conftest.c  >&5
configure:4198: $? = 0
configure:4205: ./conftest
configure:4209: $? = 0
configure:4224: result: no
configure:4229: checking for suffix of object files
configure:4251: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
configure:4255: $? = 0
configure:4276: result: o
configure:4280: checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler
configure:4299: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
configure:4299: $? = 0
configure:4308: result: yes
configure:4317: checking whether gcc accepts -g
configure:4337: gcc -c -g  conftest.c >&5
configure:4337: $? = 0
configure:4378: result: yes
configure:4395: checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89
configure:4458: gcc  -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:4458: $? = 0
configure:4471: result: none needed
configure:4502: checking for style of include used by make
configure:4530: result: GNU
configure:4556: checking dependency style of gcc
configure:4667: result: gcc3
configure:4683: checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together
configure:4714: gcc -c conftest.c -o conftest2.o >&5
configure:4718: $? = 0
configure:4724: gcc -c conftest.c -o conftest2.o >&5
configure:4728: $? = 0
configure:4739: cc -c conftest.c >&5
configure:4743: $? = 0
configure:4751: cc -c conftest.c -o conftest2.o >&5
configure:4755: $? = 0
configure:4761: cc -c conftest.c -o conftest2.o >&5
configure:4765: $? = 0
configure:4783: result: yes
configure:4810: checking for C compiler vendor
configure:4834: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
conftest.c:18:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'thisisanerror'
      thisisanerror;
      ^
1 error generated.
configure:4834: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "fftw"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "fftw"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.3.3"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "fftw 3.3.3"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "fftw@fftw.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "fftw"
| #define VERSION "3.3.3"
| #define FFTW_ENABLE_ALLOCA 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
| #if !(defined(__ICC) || defined(__ECC) || defined(__INTEL_COMPILER))
|       thisisanerror;
| #endif
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4834: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
conftest.c:18:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'thisisanerror'
      thisisanerror;
      ^
1 error generated.
configure:4834: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "fftw"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "fftw"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.3.3"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "fftw 3.3.3"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "fftw@fftw.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "fftw"
| #define VERSION "3.3.3"
| #define FFTW_ENABLE_ALLOCA 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
| #if !(defined(__xlc__) || defined(__xlC__) || defined(__IBMC__) || defined(__IBMCPP__))
|       thisisanerror;
| #endif
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4834: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
conftest.c:18:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'thisisanerror'
      thisisanerror;
      ^
1 error generated.
configure:4834: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "fftw"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "fftw"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.3.3"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "fftw 3.3.3"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "fftw@fftw.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "fftw"
| #define VERSION "3.3.3"
| #define FFTW_ENABLE_ALLOCA 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
| #if !(defined(__PATHCC__) || defined(__PATHSCALE__))
|       thisisanerror;
| #endif
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4834: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:4834: $? = 0
configure:4841: result: gnu
configure:4848: checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99
configure:4997: gcc  -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:4997: $? = 0
configure:5010: result: none needed
configure:5118: checking for gcc option to accept ISO Standard C
configure:5129: result: none needed
configure:5137: checking whether ln -s works
configure:5141: result: yes
configure:5148: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:5170: result: yes
configure:5528: checking how to print strings
configure:5555: result: printf
configure:5576: checking for a sed that does not truncate output
configure:5640: result: /usr/bin/sed
configure:5658: checking for grep that handles long lines and -e
configure:5716: result: /usr/bin/grep
configure:5721: checking for egrep
configure:5783: result: /usr/bin/grep -E
configure:5788: checking for fgrep
configure:5850: result: /usr/bin/grep -F
configure:5885: checking for ld used by gcc
configure:5952: result: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
configure:5959: checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld
configure:5974: result: no
configure:5986: checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)
configure:6035: result: /usr/bin/nm
configure:6165: checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm) interface
configure:6172: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:6175: /usr/bin/nm "conftest.o"
configure:6178: output
0000000000000208 S _some_variable
configure:6185: result: BSD nm
configure:6189: checking the maximum length of command line arguments
configure:6319: result: 196608
configure:6336: checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs
configure:6346: result: yes
configure:6350: checking whether the shell understands "+="
configure:6356: result: yes
configure:6391: checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0 file names to x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0 format
configure:6431: result: func_convert_file_noop
configure:6438: checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0 file names to toolchain format
configure:6458: result: func_convert_file_noop
configure:6465: checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files
configure:6472: result: -r
configure:6546: checking for objdump
configure:6573: result: objdump
configure:6602: checking how to recognize dependent libraries
configure:6800: result: pass_all
configure:6885: checking for dlltool
configure:6912: result: dlltool
configure:6942: checking how to associate runtime and link libraries
configure:6969: result: printf %s\n
configure:7029: checking for ar
configure:7045: found /usr/bin/ar
configure:7056: result: ar
configure:7093: checking for archiver @FILE support
configure:7110: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7110: $? = 0
configure:7113: ar cru libconftest.a @conftest.lst >&5
ar: @conftest.lst: No such file or directory
configure:7116: $? = 1
configure:7136: result: no
configure:7194: checking for strip
configure:7210: found /usr/bin/strip
configure:7221: result: strip
configure:7293: checking for ranlib
configure:7309: found /usr/bin/ranlib
configure:7320: result: ranlib
configure:7422: checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm output from gcc object
configure:7542: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7545: $? = 0
configure:7549: /usr/bin/nm conftest.o \| sed -n -e 's/^.*[ ]\([BCDEGRST][BCDEGRST]*\)[ ][ ]*\([_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*\)$/\1 \2 \2/p' | sed '/ __gnu_lto/d' \> conftest.nm
configure:7552: $? = 0
cannot find nm_test_var in conftest.nm
configure:7542: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7545: $? = 0
configure:7549: /usr/bin/nm conftest.o \| sed -n -e 's/^.*[ ]\([BCDEGRST][BCDEGRST]*\)[ ][ ]*_\([_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*\)$/\1 _\2 \2/p' | sed '/ __gnu_lto/d' \> conftest.nm
configure:7552: $? = 0
configure:7618: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c conftstm.o >&5
configure:7621: $? = 0
configure:7659: result: ok
configure:7696: checking for sysroot
configure:7726: result: no
configure:7982: checking for mt
configure:8012: result: no
configure:8032: checking if : is a manifest tool
configure:8038: : '-?'
configure:8046: result: no
configure:8102: checking for dsymutil
configure:8118: found /usr/bin/dsymutil
configure:8129: result: dsymutil
configure:8194: checking for nmedit
configure:8210: found /usr/bin/nmedit
configure:8221: result: nmedit
configure:8286: checking for lipo
configure:8302: found /usr/bin/lipo
configure:8313: result: lipo
configure:8378: checking for otool
configure:8394: found /usr/bin/otool
configure:8405: result: otool
configure:8470: checking for otool64
configure:8500: result: no
configure:8545: checking for -single_module linker flag
gcc -g -O2  -o libconftest.dylib -dynamiclib -Wl,-single_module conftest.c
configure:8578: result: yes
configure:8581: checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag
configure:8601: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,conftest.sym conftest.c  >&5
configure:8601: $? = 0
configure:8611: result: yes
configure:8614: checking for -force_load linker flag
gcc -g -O2 -c -o conftest.o conftest.c
ar cru libconftest.a conftest.o
ranlib libconftest.a
gcc -g -O2  -o conftest conftest.c -Wl,-force_load,./libconftest.a
configure:8646: result: yes
configure:8688: checking how to run the C preprocessor
configure:8719: gcc -E  conftest.c
configure:8719: $? = 0
configure:8733: gcc -E  conftest.c
conftest.c:12:10: fatal error: 'ac_nonexistent.h' file not found
#include <ac_nonexistent.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
configure:8733: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "fftw"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "fftw"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.3.3"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "fftw 3.3.3"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "fftw@fftw.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "fftw"
| #define VERSION "3.3.3"
| #define FFTW_ENABLE_ALLOCA 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
configure:8758: result: gcc -E
configure:8778: gcc -E  conftest.c
configure:8778: $? = 0
configure:8792: gcc -E  conftest.c
conftest.c:12:10: fatal error: 'ac_nonexistent.h' file not found
#include <ac_nonexistent.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
configure:8792: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
```

………….and so on…..below is the end:

```
## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /Users/admin/Downloads/fftw-3.3.3/missing --run aclocal-1.11'
ALLOCA=''
ALTIVEC_CFLAGS=''
AMDEPBACKSLASH='\'
AMDEP_FALSE='#'
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AR='ar'
AS='as'
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /Users/admin/Downloads/fftw-3.3.3/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /Users/admin/Downloads/fftw-3.3.3/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /Users/admin/Downloads/fftw-3.3.3/missing --run automake-1.11'
AVX_CFLAGS=''
AWK='awk'
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE='depmode=gcc3'
CFLAGS='-O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=native -malign-double -fstrict-aliasing -fno-schedule-insns -ffast-math'
CHECK_PL_OPTS=''
COMBINED_THREADS_FALSE=''
COMBINED_THREADS_TRUE='#'
CPP='gcc -E'
CPPFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
C_FFTW_R2R_KIND='C_INT32_T'
C_MPI_FINT=''
DEFS='-DHAVE_CONFIG_H'
DEPDIR='.deps'
DLLTOOL='dlltool'
DSYMUTIL='dsymutil'
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP='/usr/bin/grep -E'
EXEEXT=''
F77='gfortran'
FFLAGS='-g -O2'
FGREP='/usr/bin/grep -F'
FLIBS=' -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12/4.8.2 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12/4.8.2/../../.. -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm'
GREP='/usr/bin/grep'
HAVE_ALTIVEC_FALSE=''
HAVE_ALTIVEC_TRUE='#'
HAVE_AVX_FALSE=''
HAVE_AVX_TRUE='#'
HAVE_NEON_FALSE=''
HAVE_NEON_TRUE='#'
HAVE_SSE2_FALSE=''
HAVE_SSE2_TRUE='#'
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LD='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld'
LDFLAGS=''
LDOUBLE_FALSE=''
LDOUBLE_TRUE='#'
LIBOBJS=''
LIBQUADMATH=''
LIBS='-lm '
LIBTOOL='$(SHELL) $(top_builddir)/libtool'
LIPO='lipo'
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINT='#'
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE='#'
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /Users/admin/Downloads/fftw-3.3.3/missing --run makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=':'
MKDIR_P='./install-sh -c -d'
MPICC=''
MPILIBS=''
MPIRUN=''
MPI_FALSE=''
MPI_TRUE='#'
NEON_CFLAGS=''
NM='/usr/bin/nm'
NMEDIT='nmedit'
OBJDUMP='objdump'
OBJEXT='o'
OCAMLBUILD=''
OPENMP_CFLAGS=''
OPENMP_FALSE=''
OPENMP_TRUE='#'
OTOOL64=':'
OTOOL='otool'
PACKAGE='fftw'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='fftw@fftw.org'
PACKAGE_NAME='fftw'
PACKAGE_STRING='fftw 3.3.3'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='fftw'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='3.3.3'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
POW_LIB=''
PRECISION='d'
PREC_SUFFIX=''
PTHREAD_CC=''
PTHREAD_CFLAGS=''
PTHREAD_LIBS=''
QUAD_FALSE=''
QUAD_TRUE='#'
RANLIB='ranlib'
SED='/usr/bin/sed'
SET_MAKE=''
SHARED_VERSION_INFO='6:2:3'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SINGLE_FALSE=''
SINGLE_TRUE='#'
SMP_FALSE=''
SMP_TRUE='#'
SSE2_CFLAGS=''
STACK_ALIGN_CFLAGS=''
STRIP='strip'
THREADLIBS=''
THREADS_FALSE=''
THREADS_TRUE='#'
VERSION='3.3.3'
ac_ct_AR='ar'
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
ac_ct_F77='gfortran'
acx_pthread_config=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE='#'
am__fastdepCC_FALSE='#'
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include='include'
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep='_no'
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='darwin12.5.0'
build_vendor='apple'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='${prefix}'
host='x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='darwin12.5.0'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /Users/admin/Downloads/fftw-3.3.3/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(top_builddir)/./install-sh -c -d'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/usr/local'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "fftw"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "fftw"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.3.3"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "fftw 3.3.3"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "fftw@fftw.org"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "fftw"
#define VERSION "3.3.3"
#define FFTW_ENABLE_ALLOCA 1
#define STDC_HEADERS 1
#define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
#define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
#define HAVE_STRING_H 1
#define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
#define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
#define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
#define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
#define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
#define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
#define STDC_HEADERS 1
#define HAVE_STDDEF_H 1
#define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
#define HAVE_STRING_H 1
#define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_TIME_H 1
#define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
#define HAVE_LIMITS_H 1
#define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
#define HAVE_MACH_MACH_TIME_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_SYSCTL_H 1
#define TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME 1
#define HAVE_LONG_DOUBLE 1
#define SIZEOF_INT 4
#define SIZEOF_UNSIGNED_INT 4
#define SIZEOF_LONG 8
#define SIZEOF_UNSIGNED_LONG 8
#define SIZEOF_LONG_LONG 8
#define SIZEOF_UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG 8
#define SIZEOF_SIZE_T 8
#define SIZEOF_PTRDIFF_T 8
#define HAVE_UINTPTR_T 1
#define SIZEOF_FLOAT 4
#define SIZEOF_DOUBLE 8
#define SIZEOF_FFTW_R2R_KIND 4
#define HAVE_ALLOCA_H 1
#define HAVE_ALLOCA 1
#define HAVE_VPRINTF 1
#define HAVE_LIBM 1
#define HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY 1
#define HAVE_DRAND48 1
#define HAVE_SQRT 1
#define HAVE_MEMSET 1
#define HAVE_POSIX_MEMALIGN 1
#define HAVE_MACH_ABSOLUTE_TIME 1
#define HAVE_SYSCTL 1
#define HAVE_ABORT 1
#define HAVE_SINL 1
#define HAVE_COSL 1
#define HAVE_SNPRINTF 1
#define HAVE_DECL_DRAND48 1
#define HAVE_DECL_SRAND48 1
#define HAVE_DECL_MEMALIGN 0
#define HAVE_DECL_POSIX_MEMALIGN 1
#define HAVE_DECL_SINL 1
#define HAVE_DECL_COSL 1
#define HAVE_DECL_SINQ 0
#define HAVE_DECL_COSQ 0
#define HAVE_ISNAN 1
#define F77_FUNC(name,NAME) name ## _
#define F77_FUNC_(name,NAME) name ## _
#define F77_FUNC_EQUIV 1
#define WITH_G77_WRAPPERS 1
#define FFTW_CC "gcc -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=native -malign-double -fstrict-aliasing -fno-schedule-insns -ffast-math"

configure: exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that Apple redirect all GCC calls to clang. Configure thinks it is using GCC and uses an incompatible syntax, thus Clang fails.

You have either look for a more recent version of your tools which fixed the issue. Or you have to look for specific flags to tell configure which compiler to use. Try to set the shell variables `CC`, `CXX` or there might be a specific configure flag, ask `configure --help`

The other possibility would be to install GCC. Using macports or homebrew this is rather simpler. But it could be that one of these offers you MPI and FFTW, so you could use these.

Comment: This was the case for me, so I installed gcc with Homebrew and then looked for the program's name in /usr/local/bin. It was gcc-6. Then I configured using `./configure CC="gcc-6"`. It worked! Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried to follow @basfest suggestion but bumped on to similar error `gcc-6: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'`

Comment: CC="gcc" ./configure solved the problem, while I was building secp256k1 on Mac. Default compiler is llvm.

Comment: dang still getting -V with both CC=gcc-10 and clang masquerading as gcc on the path in /usr/bin