# treemix configure error on MacOS 10.12.4

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang, macos-sierra

I got a compiling error to install [treemix 1.3](https://bitbucket.org/nygcresearch/treemix/) on the latest MacOS 10.12.4 (Sierra). I tried some commands according to the similar problems like [the issue in the treemix group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/structure-software/xes3ju0TzPc) and [the question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132805/configure-error-with-mac-os-x-10-8-5-xcode-5-0-2-clang-error-argument-to-v).

What should I do next? Is it better to re-install gcc or g++ through homebrew?

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local CPPFLAGS=-l/usr/local/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib CC=g++
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/kfdas/Downloads/treemix-1.13': 
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Then see config.log,

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by TreeMix configure 1.13, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local CPPFLAGS=-l/usr/local/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib CC=g++

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = kfdas.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 16.5.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 16.5.0: Fri Mar  3 16:52:33 PST 2017; root:xnu-3789.51.2~3/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 16.5.0: Fri Mar  3 16:52:33 PST 2017; root:xnu-3789.51.2~3/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: x86_64h (Intel x86-64h Haswell)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 16.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 331 tasks, 1461 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 1.18, Mach factor: 2.81
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /Users/kfdas/anaconda/bin
PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: /Users/kfdas/.cabal/bin
PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /Users/kfdas/opt/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /opt/X11/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1957: checking for g++
configure:1973: found /usr/bin/g++
configure:1984: result: g++
configure:2011: checking for C++ compiler version
configure:2020: g++ --version >&5
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
configure:2031: $? = 0
configure:2020: g++ -v >&5
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
configure:2031: $? = 0
configure:2020: g++ -V >&5
clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang: error: no input files
configure:2031: $? = 1
configure:2020: g++ -qversion >&5
clang: error: unknown argument: '-qversion'
clang: error: no input files
configure:2031: $? = 1
configure:2051: checking whether the C++ compiler works
configure:2073: g++  -l/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib conftest.cpp  >&5
ld: library not found for -l/usr/local/include
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
configure:2077: $? = 1
configure:2115: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "TreeMix"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "treemix"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.13"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "TreeMix 1.13"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "joepickrell@gmail.com"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://treemix.googlecode.com/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2120: error: in `/Users/kfdas/Downloads/treemix-1.13':
configure:2122: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=g++
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=-Qunused-arguments
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=-l/usr/local/include
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=-L/usr/local/lib
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CXX=g++

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL=''
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR=''
AM_BACKSLASH=''
AM_DEFAULT_V=''
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY=''
AM_V=''
AUTOCONF=''
AUTOHEADER=''
AUTOMAKE=''
AWK=''
BOOST_CPPFLAGS=''
BOOST_LDFLAGS=''
CC='g++'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS='-Qunused-arguments'
CPPFLAGS='-l/usr/local/include'
CXX='g++'
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W=''
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EXEEXT=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM=''
LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/lib'
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEINFO=''
MKDIR_P=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='joepickrell@gmail.com'
PACKAGE_NAME='TreeMix'
PACKAGE_STRING='TreeMix 1.13'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='treemix'
PACKAGE_URL='http://treemix.googlecode.com/'
PACKAGE_VERSION='1.13'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
VERSION=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX='g++'
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot=''
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar=''
am__untar=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host_alias=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p=''
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/usr/local'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "TreeMix"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "treemix"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.13"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "TreeMix 1.13"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "joepickrell@gmail.com"
#define PACKAGE_URL "http://treemix.googlecode.com/"

configure: exit 77
```

I got the same result without `CC=g++` option.

versions of g++ and gcc are

```
$ g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin


$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

$ brew info gsl
gsl: stable 2.3 (bottled)
Numerical library for C and C++
https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/
/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.3 (273 files, 8.6MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2017-05-12 at 13:07:01
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/gsl.rb
```

Comment: I installed gcc6 (stable 6.3.0) through homebrew and still I have the same problem to run configure.