# Cannot create executables, clang behaves weirdly on MacOS

Tags: c, makefile, clang

So there is a CMakeLists.txt that downloads a package from the internet, specifically `libtiff-3.9.1`, it's written in C, and my System auto detects clang to be my default system compiler. The problem now is that when I run the make command, I get the following error message:

```
[ 28%] Performing configure step for 'libtiff-3.9.6'
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin21.5.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin21.5.0
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... config/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/ziadmalik/Desktop/project/amongus/build/_deps/libtiff-3.9.6/src':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

here are the relevant contents of `config.log`:

```
configure:3675: checking for C compiler version
configure:3684: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc --version >&5
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
configure:3695: $? = 0
configure:3684: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -v >&5
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
configure:3695: $? = 0
configure:3684: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -V >&5
clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang: error: no input files
configure:3695: $? = 1
configure:3684: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -qversion >&5
clang: error: unknown argument '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
clang: error: no input files
configure:3695: $? = 1
configure:3715: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3737: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -O3 -DNDEBUG -Wno-everything   conftest.c  >&5
ld: library not found for -lSystem
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
configure:3741: $? = 1
configure:3779: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "LibTIFF Software"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "tiff"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.9.6"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "LibTIFF Software 3.9.6"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "tiff@lists.maptools.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "tiff"
| #define VERSION "3.9.6"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| int
| main ()
| {
|
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3784: error: in `/Users/ziadmalik/Desktop/project/amongus/build/_deps/libtiff-3.9.6/src':
configure:3786: error: C compiler
```

I tried a lot of things, kind of desperate, why does clang say no input files?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to build?

Comment: Here is your first error: `configure:3684: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -V >&5
clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)`. And the related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132805/configure-error-with-mac-os-x-10-8-5-xcode-5-0-2-clang-error-argument-to-v). TL/DR, set your compiler to `gcc`, as `clang` does not support the passed options.